# MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./scWeb ..... JBAS018040: Failed to start context

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, legacy, legacy-app

I am getting following error as part my deployment. Actually I am deploying Websphere application in JBoss. I am sorting out issues one by one.

Please guide me if anyone aware of this error. If you need any other configuration details I can furnish.

```
12:01:36,228 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /scWeb start, will stop it
12:01:36,228 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) ERROR [ServerService Thread Pool -- 111] (StandardContext.java:3841) - JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /scWeb start, will stop it

12:01:36,228 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.web.session.DistributableSessionManager.scWeb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) Stopping
12:01:36,228 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) DEBUG [ServerService Thread Pool -- 111] (DistributableSessionManager.java:396) - Stopping

12:01:36,228 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.web.session.DistributableSessionManager.scWeb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) Closing off LockingValve
12:01:36,228 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) DEBUG [ServerService Thread Pool -- 111] (DistributableSessionManager.java:415) - Closing off LockingValve

12:01:36,228 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 111) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./scWeb: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./scWeb: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:168)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: The actual reason for this error,- `JBAS018040: Failed to start` will be differing by situation, however, it clearly states the problem is `Spring Application Context` meaning whatever injection we do through by container.

Answer (score 1):

`web.xml` has following spring configuration for dependency injection....

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and Context Loader Listener for Struts in `web.xml`...

```
<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And `ApplicationContext-config.xml` has following bean reference...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
 <bean id="userRoleService" class="com.singtel.pcb.sam.dto.UserRoleService">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

Wherein this particular bean is part of other .war.... I had removed the compiled server-side classes,- `samWeb.jar` from `scWeb.war\WEB-INF\lib`... This had caused the above error....

Hence this error had occurred....

> JBAS018040: Failed to start context
>       at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:99)

While I redo the build activity this had gone.... So I come to know that this was the issue... Basically I am porting my application from Websphere to JBoss... I am trying mix & match of activities....

Comment: Here it is IOC Container....... dependency injection is something different from IOC container.... Here `web.xml` has IOC Container Configuration.... dependency injection is advancement in IOC Concepts....